# Date comparison in Java not valid

Tags: java, date, comparator, comparable

I need to compare the attribute "date" of objects included in an ArrayList.
The objects included in the ArrayList are of type "Books" and each Book has a launching date.
The date is given in a String format.

```
public ArrayList<Book> group;
```

What I have done is :

```
public static Comparator<Book> ComparaisonDate = new Comparator<Book>() {
        SimpleDateFormat data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        @Override
        public int compare(Book l1, Book l2) {
            try {
                return data.parse(l1.launchingDate).compareTo(data.parse(l2.launchingDate));
            } catch (ParseException e)  {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    };




public void sort(int option) {
        Collections.sort(this.group, Book.ComparaisonDate);
    }
```

When I add two books with the dates: 01/08/2020 and 12/05/2020 the result of the sort() function is:

```
01/08/2020
12/05/2020
```

The result should be: `12/05/2020` and then `01/05/2020`.From what I can see, it compares only the day and not the month or year. Do you have any idea how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Use MM (uppercase), not mm, for the month format.

Comment: Incidentally, you might consider changing your data model so these dates are represented as [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of strings.

Comment: @dnault in my experience, LocalDate is calling for trouble if it is used in companies with locations in different time zones. Use UTC at the backend, and, if really necessary, convert it to local time in the frontend, and the frontend only. You will still have errors based on missing conversions to- and from the frontend.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Yes, we are in agreement that time zones are important, and UTC is a good way to ensure interoperability across different regions. I would maintain that `LocalDate` in still appropriate in this case because a Book's "date" does not have time zone information, and using a specialized datatype is generally preferable to smuggling data in a String. One could argue that a book's launch date *should* have a time zone associated with it, but then we're straying waaaay far afield from OP's original question ;-)

Comment: @dnault I mostly agree, but if you are located in the US and have co-workers in Japan, this might make a days difference and stir confusion if read from the terminal and then transmitted by email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mm` in the pattern stands for Minutes of the Hour, therefore the sorting is actually correct. You need `MM`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for valid patterns.